# How to save image from drawable resource to sd card?

Tags: java, android, xml, drawable

So, i have a view like on the image below. Plus I will add a Save button. You can also see my XML file. I am using this code to load image from drawable folder by pressing the next and previous buttons:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.bNext:
            a++;
            setImage(a);
            break;
        case R.id.bPrevious:
            if(a>0)
            {
                a--;
                setImage(a);  
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private void setImage(int a){
        if (a == 0)
        {
        slika.setImageResource(R.drawable.l2);
        a = 1;
        }
        else if (a == 1)
        {
        slika.setImageResource(R.drawable.l3);
        a = 2;
        }
        else if (a == 2)
        {
        slika.setImageResource(R.drawable.l4);
        a = 3;
        }
        else if (a == 3)
        {
        slika.setImageResource(R.drawable.l5);
        a = 4;
        }
        else if (a == 4)
        {
        slika.setImageResource(R.drawable.l6);
        a = 5;
        }
.
.
.
.
.
        else if (a == 55)
        {
        slika.setImageResource(R.drawable.l57);
        a = 56;
        }
        }
```

I need to save the image that is currently on the screen. I found some answers on stackoverflow, but those are all for specific image with known name. I don't know what image a user will want to save.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bMenu"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttons"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Menu"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="23dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bNext"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttons"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textSize="23dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bPrevious"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttons"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Previous"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="23dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String folder = "/sdcard/Pictures/MyAppFolder";

void save(){  
    Imageview  view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cachesView);
    view.buildDrawingCache(); 
    Bitmap yourBitmap = view.getDrawingCache();  
    final File myDir = new File(folder);
    myDir.mkdirs();
    final Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    final String fname = "StyleMe-" + n + ".png";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists()) {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        yourBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        sendBroadcast(
            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
            Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()))
        ); // this will refresh the gallery app.
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

### please see

add this method in your class and on click button put

```
save();
```

Comment: Yes, but how to know what is currently "yourBitmap" on the screen?

Comment: I get some errors. "final File myDir = new File(folder);" on folder. Can you tell what part of your snippet I should place in my button's onclicklistener, and what as a class member?

Comment: String folder = "/sdcard/Pictures/Name of your CHOICE";

Comment: Do you get an error when the code doesn't work? You're supposed to call this `save()` method in your buttons `onClick()` method.